# Undefined variable in SASS, even though the variable is defined above

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I have SASS installed through Ruby on my Mac and currently have it listening for changes in the file **styles.sass** and precompiling those changes into the file **styles.css**. The entire code was precompiled error free until I replaced the color I am using for the background of much of my site — #194719 — with the variable $pageGreen. I define $pageGreen at the top of my SASS file —

```css
    /* VARIABLES */

        $pageGreen: #194719
```

— and then replaced all instances where I used the color with the variable. Here’s an example of where I used this variable (lines 39 thru 45):

```css
    .strip 
        height: 180px
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
        background-color: $pageGreen
        color: white
        position: relative
        min-width: 995px
```

Upon saving, I got an error.

```css
    >>> Change detected to: styles.sass
          error styles.sass (Line 42: Undefined variable: "$pageGreen”.)
```

What am I doing wrong? I am happy to post my entire code if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using [indented syntax](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html) in your sass file. It also looks like your variable declaration is quite indented.

I suspect that this indentation makes the variable scoped, which means that it is not available outside the scope.

Try un-indenting the variable declaration:

```css
/* VARIABLES */
$pageGreen: #194719 /* <-- not indented at all */


.strip 
    height: 180px
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
    background-color: $pageGreen
    color: white
    position: relative
    min-width: 995px
```